# Zend_Db_Adapter_Sqlsrv insert date sql server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework, zend-db

I'm connecting to SQL Server using the Zend_Db_Adapter_Sqlsrv via SQL Server driver for PHP

Wondering how I can insert a date which is read in from a web form in format dd/mm/yyyy into a datetime column

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using zend_date or strtotime() and date()

Comment: $date = new Zend_Date('13/10/2009','dd/mm/yyyy');

Inserting into a datetime column using $date works fine